# Different values between sklearn TruncatedSVD and MLLib SVD?

Tags: scala, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib, svd

I'm using dimensionality reduction in a project. I started a proof of concept in Python, and then proceeded to scala.

I used TruncatedSVD in python, and SVD in scala. My math is really not on point with SVD, but I tested a few things and was happy with the results.

I'm now noticing something that I can't quite explain though, and this is making me question my scala code.

I tried TruncatedSVD (python) and SVD (scala) on the same data, aiming for a 2D output, and I get different values.

Anyone could explain to me why I don't get the same results ? Here's the code, both in python and then in scala.

Python:

```
    from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
    import numpy as np
    l = [np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]), 
    np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]), 
    np.array([0.25, 0.33, 0.54, 0.87]), 
    np.array([0.12, 0.89, 0.12, 0.35])]

    data2D = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2).fit_transform(l)
    print(data2D)
    array([
       [ 0.49114514, -0.08966268],
       [ 0.49114514, -0.08966268],
       [ 1.0559638 , -0.32304442],
       [ 0.81691343,  0.5253898 ]])
```

Scala:

```
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrix, SingularValueDecomposition, Vector, Vectors}
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix


    val vectors =  sc.parallelize(Array(
    Vectors.dense(Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)),
    Vectors.dense(Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)), 
    Vectors.dense(Array(0.25, 0.33, 0.54, 0.87)), 
    Vectors.dense(Array(0.12, 0.89, 0.12, 0.35))))

    val matrix : RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(vectors)
    val svd : SingularValueDecomposition[RowMatrix, Matrix] = matrix.computeSVD(2, computeU = true)
    val data2D = svd.U.rows
    data2D.foreach(println)

    [-0.32635459035606795,0.14239870001655083]
    [-0.32635459035606795,0.14239870001655083]
    [-0.7016635327093717,0.5130463060403057]
    [-0.542820089507427,-0.8344032048869356]
```

I see the same two original vectors have the same 2D representation, but that's it. Am I using this the wrong way ? What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot

JT

EDIT:

Results with non-squared matrix, where I added 0.18 at the end of each vector:

Python:

```
    array([[ 0.51885074, -0.08919845],
       [ 0.51885074, -0.08919845],
       [ 1.06938646, -0.32415061],
       [ 0.83672766,  0.52490632]])
```

Scala (with s and V objects)

```
svd.U.rows:
(-0.19794364441758672  0.09051048659772198,
-0.5478856677155637   -0.818428534757707,
-0.37169369848891953  0.3725778323351847,
-0.6877514437772323   0.42786133587825526,
-0.22244404876848498  -0.010149946949985795)

svd.V:
(-0.19794364441758672  0.09051048659772198,
-0.5478856677155637   -0.818428534757707,
-0.37169369848891953  0.3725778323351847,
-0.6877514437772323   0.42786133587825526,
-0.22244404876848498  -0.010149946949985795) 

svd.s:
[1.5434094639966702,0.6296927732607006]
```

Comment: What is `TruncatedSVD(n_components=2).fit_transform(l)` in python code returning, exactly? Couldn't you test it on some non-square input matrix, and then print the `U`, `V`, and the singular values, and then show python's and mllib's output side-by side? At least the singular values should be roughly the same (assuming that they are sorted in same order).

Comment: Related: [How unique or non-unique are U and V in SVD?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644327/how-unique-on-non-unique-are-u-and-v-in-singular-value-decomposition-svd).

Comment: Hi Andrey, the resut for each output is printed in the post :) I only put the output of U because it's the one I'm interested in (the one showing that the first two vectors contain the same values after dimensionality reduction).

Comment: Please, not in the comments... There is a little gray 'edit' button in the left bottom corner right under your question... Put it into formatted blocks in the question.

Comment: I've already linked a link that explains in which ways `U` is not unique. Here is a quote from Wikipedia, if you prefer that: *"In general, the SVD is unique up to arbitrary unitary transformations applied uniformly to the column vectors of both U and V spanning the subspaces of each singular value, and up to arbitrary unitary transformations on vectors of U and V spanning the kernel and cokernel, respectively, of M"*. So, unless you are able to perform unitary transformations in five dimensional space in your head, you won't immediately recognize how those `U`s are "essentially the same".

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post, I've had a quick look at the link you sent, but I will need to spend some time on it, I'll read it more thoroughly as soon as I can.